# Incompatible types error using lombok.Getter(lazy = true) with java 10

Tags: java, lombok, java-10

I'm trying to do some caching using `reactor`, `reactor.ipc.netty.http.client.HttpClient` and initialize it as lazy getter field with lombok's `@Getter(lazy = true)`.

All works fine with Java 8 but fails to compile with `error: incompatible types: Duration cannot be converted to String` with Java 10 on this snippet

```
@Value
public static class Translations {

    Map<String, Translation> translations;

    @Value
    public static class Translation {

        Map<String, String> content;

    }
}

@Getter(lazy = true)
Mono<Map<String, Translations.Translation>> translations = httpClient
        .get(String.format("%s/translations/%s", endpoint, translationGroup), Function.identity())
        .flatMap(it -> it.receive().aggregate().asByteArray())
        .map(byteArray -> {
            try {
                return objectMapper.readValue(byteArray, Translations.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException("Failed to get translation for " + translationGroup, e);
            }
        })
        .map(Translations::getTranslations)
        .retryWhen(it -> it.delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(200)))
        .cache(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

but it compiles perfectly fine with

```
@Getter(lazy = true)
Mono<Map<String, Translations.Translation>> translations = Mono.just(new byte[]{})
        .map(byteArray -> {
            try {
                return objectMapper.readValue(byteArray, Translations.class);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException("Failed to get translation for " + translationGroup, e);
            }
        })
        .map(Translations::getTranslations)
        .retryWhen(it -> it.delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(200)))
        .cache(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

How to know what's wrong and how its possible to workaround?

Comment: could you share the import or definition for `Translations.Translation` as well? to help creating an MCVE

Comment: @nullpointer updated example with the definition.

Comment: (pardon me typing in half sleep) both your code block compiles fine for me with Java 11, can you provide a complete MCVE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to move the initialization code to a separate method.

```
@Getter(lazy=true)
SomeType t = <complicatedInitializationCode>;
```

becomes

```
@Getter(lazy=true)
SomeType t = initializeT();

private SomeType initializeT() {
    return <complicatedInitializationCode>;
}
```

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.